# Working Talmid Chochum

Tags: history, employment

In Jewish history, amongst the rishonim and achronim (and achrei achronim), who were known to be Talmidei Chachumim (either due to their seforim or just facts) and Businessmen (employee counts)?

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as a duplicate of "_Talmudic personages and their occupations_": That question seems to be asking about people in the [Mishnah and] Talmud who had other occupations, whereas this one is asking about _post_-Talmudic people ("amongst the rishonim and achronim") who had other occupations.

Comment: @TamirEvan yup, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exhaustive list by far, but here's a few:

Rashi-[vineyard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi#cite_note-20)

Rambam- [doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides#cite_note-frank-36)

Ramban- [doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides#cite_note-4)

Ramchal- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Luzzatto) claims that he was a diamond cutter. I remember reading that he made lenses and was involved in glass cutting and shaping.

Chayei Adam- merchant (he writes about it in his hakdama to chochmas adam)

Pischei Choshen (Rav Y.Y. Blau- dayan for the eide chareidis)- banker (During the hespedim given when he passed away, one of the speakers mentioned that he refused to work in rabbonus and supported himself as a banker. That's where he gained his expertise in Choshen mishpat and business matters. Eventually the Minchas Yitzchok convinced him to serve as a dayan on the Eida. I'm going to try to see if there's a source for it.)

(I believe the Levush worked in textiles, and there's a very interesting story about him fighting off a woman trying to seduce him that involved his clothing, and that's why he named his work the Levush. But I don't remember the story or where it can be found.)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcha_Bunim_of_Peshischa

Comment: This answer could be improved with your sources for these claims.

Comment: @TamirEvan You're right. I quickly added a couple of sources. As I find more, I'll put them up.